# CMake Error: fatal error : boost/asio.hpp not found without using find_package() for boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

Like the heading says I don't wanna use the **find_package(Boost)** to locate Boost and then the **Asio** component in it rather I want to do by creating a **target** library, and then link the target to my executable like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(final_exe_proj VERSION 1.0)

add_executable(final_exe main.cpp)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_library(boost_asio INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(boost_asio INTERFACE /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp)
target_link_libraries(boost_asio INTERFACE Threads::Threads)

target_link_libraries(final_exe PRIVATE boost_asio)
```

I have tried doing **#include <asio.hpp>** but still no luck. What is the right way to do it? Really would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Happy New Year!

Comment: `target_include_directories` should be a directory (`/usr/local/include`) not a file

Comment: Oh my! That solved it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alan! The issue was in the line **target_include_directories**

On changing that too

```
target_include_directories(boost_asio INTERFACE /usr/local/include)
```

In a way this adds to the path for this project, so now the compiler will be able to find **#include <boost/asio.hpp>**